# Groovy - XML Slurper Parse SoapResponse instead of File

Tags: xml, soap, groovy

I'm trying to parse a SOAP object - I am looking at the XML slurper in Groovy, but it wants to read from an XML file. I would prefer to avoid the file (there are going to be millions of lines, writing to a file isn't too practical) - is there a way to pass the SOAPResponse object to XMLSluper instead of a file?

`SOAPMessage soapResponse;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XMLSlurper` provides a series of overloaded `parse` methods and a `parseText` method that can read XML input in the following formats

- File
- InputSource
- InputStream
- Reader
- String
- URI

You didn't mention the type of your `SOAPResponse` object, but it's highly likely it's one of the above (or can easily be converted to one of these).

Comment: Oh, right - it's SOAPMessage as the type for SOAPResponse

Comment: I've been trying to find a good way to transform the soapResponse to a string to pass in - I saw the overloads - if I feed the response as a SOAPMessage I get an invalid parameter error - its still looking for a file

Comment: We used the `transformerFactory` class to convert the response to a string, then `parseText()` - and it works fine. thanks guys

Comment: Assuming `SOAPMessage` is itself an object representation of the SOAP (XML) message it seems that using this approach you'll end up parsing the XML twice?

Answer (score 1):

- XmlSluprer can read XML from arbitrary sources, not just a file. You can do somehting like:

  InputStream in = ...// point to your data stream
  def parsedData = new XmlSlurper().parse(in)

That will get you the SOAP object as a GPathResult you can manipulate.

- if this is a valid SOAP object, from a source whose schema is stable, you might be better off using a mechanism which was intended to do just that in the first place. You can either use the classic java JAXB mechanism, or do in in a more groovy way using [GroovyWS](http://groovy.codehaus.org/GroovyWS) .

Good luck !